# MySQL why EXPLAIN result is confusing?

Tags: mysql, explain

**Below is my Query:**

```
select  *
    from (
        SELECT  *
            from  Player
            where  Country_Name in (1,2)
         ) as A
    inner join  Country C  ON A.Country_Name=C.Country_Id;
```

> When i execute that Query i got **301 Rows** but when i use `EXPLAIN`
>   the output shows **Rows 42 and 2**.

**Below is EXPLAIN Output:**

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref                   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | C      | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY      | 4       | NULL                  |    2 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Player | NULL       | ref   | Country_Name  | Country_Name | 4       | database.C.Country_Id |   42 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

> Why there is negative difference between **Output Rows** and **Explain
>   Rows**? Is not they will be same or more?

Answer (score 1):

The `rows` column of EXPLAIN output is an **estimate** of the *rows to be **examined***. Thus, value of this column and number of rows returned on executing the command can be different.

Comment: yeah i know that but that don't means that `EXPLAIN` estimate will be lower than required, it can be higher. also not in that case, many more times i notice that `EXPLAIN` shows estimate row lot lower than it examined. so that's really hurting me as i'm unable to find out my query efficiency. also there is no clear documentation on MySQL website, how it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, EXPLAIN shows the number of `examined` rows. Suppose your query returns 0 rows, but MySQL needs to do a full table scan. `EXPLAIN` will show the number of rows in the table, not 0. However this doesn't really answer your question, since the number returned by `EXPLAIN` is lower than the rows you get.

The other thing you should know is that the number of rows you see is an approximation. In some cases it will be exact. Most of the times it will be close to the reality. Sometimes it will be completely wrong, which means that the table statistics are outdated and an `ANALYZE TABLE` is needed.

Comment: yeah i know that but that don't means that `EXPLAIN` estimate will be lower than required, it can be higher. also not in that case, many more times i notice that `EXPLAIN` shows estimate row lot lower than it examined, also **my all table is up to date**. so that's really hurting me as i'm unable to find out my query efficiency. also there is no clear documentation on MySQL website, how it works.

Comment: Even after an ANALYZE TABLE the optimizer statistics will never have all your tables data precise. It would require queries that are simply not doable in non-trivial databases. Instead it does 10 random dives into indexes, and makes statistics on that sample. And that would be useless: the optimiser's purpose is to decide a proper query plan, not to tell you in advance how many rows you will get (that would require a magic spell). I think that your numbers are ok, unless you are observing some misbehaviour.

Answer (score 0):

(I'll get to your question in a minute.)

How about simplifying it to

```
select  *
    from Player AS A
    inner join  Country C  ON A.Country_Name=C.Country_Id;
    where  p.Country_Name in (1,2)
```

Are your country "names" really "1" and "2"?

Most "Row" counts in `EXPLAIN` are estimates.  They can be quite far off.  There is *no* reliable way to get its counts to be reliable, or even consistent.

For the query as you wrote it, you need

```
Player:  INDEX(country_name)
Country: INDEX(country_id)   (or possibly PRIMARY KEY)
```

What version are you running?  I'm surprised that it *started* with `C` and managed to realize that only 2 rows need be looked at, because, effectively, `C.Country_Id IN (1,2)`.  Then it looked in `Player` and used `A.Country_Name`.

It is as if it converted what you wrote into what I wrote.

Please try this:  Run `SHOW WARNINGS;` immediately after doing the `EXPLAIN`.  The output may show a radically different query -- and make the `EXPLAIN` more obvious.  (If there are no warnings, then change to `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;`)